# Which type do I use to represent an arbitrary blob in Java?

Tags: java, data-modeling

I have an application that may receive data via various methods and in various formats. I have pluggable receivers that somehow acquire the data (e. g. by polling a mailbox, listening for HTTP requests, watch the content of a directory etc.), associate it with a MIME type and then pass it on wrapped like this:

```
public class Transmission {
    private String origin;      // where the data came from
    private String destination; // where the data was sent to
    private String mime;        // the MIME type of the data
    private BLOB data;          // this is what I need an appropriate type for
}
```

Further down the line, the data is processed by specialized handlers according to the value of the `mime` field. I'm expecting things like ZIP files, Excel documents, SOAP, generic XML, plain text and more. At this point, the code should be agnostic as to what's in the data. What is an appropriate type for the `data` field? `Object`? `InputStream`? `Byte[]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Multiple Possibilities:

- byte[]

  - the most direct way
- [ByteBuffer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html)

  - flexible
  - has random access and bulk operations
  - has operations for duplicating, slicing, etc
  - preferable if IO/Network intensive (NIO)
- [InputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html)

  - allows pipelining if done right
  - has no support of random access or bulk operations.
  - Not as flexible as the ByteBuffer.

I would not use Blob, because putting DB-related stuff into our main model seems strange.

Answer (score 5):

I would go with either `byte[]` or `InputStream`, preferring the stream since it is more flexible. You can use a `ByteArrayInputStream` to feed it an array of bytes, if need be. But you can't do it the other way around.

There is also the benefit of memory efficiency, since the stream can handle large chunks of external data without much memory. If you use `byte[]` you need to load all the data to memory. In other words, the stream is lazy.

Comment: byte[] yes, Byte[] absolutely NO!

Comment: An InputStream can only be read once, generally speaking. Not a good idea in a data model.

Comment: @skaffman: I didn't knew that (not a Java expert). You're right.

Comment: skaffman - surely that's the point of this "Transmission" object - passing it onto a "Transmission Consumer" that consumes it the once. If that means it consumes it into a byte[]/XML/hamsterdancevideo internally before processing it, that's fine.

Comment: @Brian: The implementation doesn't matter. It reads stuff from places. That's what's needed/intended.

Comment: @JeeBee - who says it's going to a TransmissionConsumer that consumes it once ?

Comment: Martinho - It's a good answer when you consider the context of the original question.

Comment: @Martinho - surely the implemetation does matter, since you may instantiate the Tranmission object from a datasource, and want to hold it separate from that source. e.g. instantiate and then your db goes down (maybe not - but that's why I think the implementation is important - you'll note I'm not fussed *what* that implementation is)

Comment: Brian - It is good to use an interface or higher up abstract class when that is sensible. Who cares if it is a ByteArrayInputStream, MemoryInputStream, ZipInputStream, VideoInputStream - only the consumers care, and they're instantiated from the mime type anyway and will throw an exception if the stream type isn't as expected.

Comment: @Brian: If you want to hold it separate from the db you can cache it into a byte[] (or something else) and pass ByteArrayInputStream (what I called MemoryStream in the answer). If you don't need to hold it separate, you can still use the InputStream... But you can't do that with the byte[]

Answer (score 0):

In your above class I would make it a **byte[]**. Why not a java.sql.Blob ? So your `Transmission` object is SQL (or datastore) agnostic.

e.g. you may at some stage want to write it a Javaspace, CouchDb or something else that isn't a SQL database. By storing it as a byte array this info is in it's basic form, and you can translate it as you wish. If your byte[] is really sizable, then your `Transmission` object can handle caching via disk etc. But I would worry about that later.

EDIT: Reference to SQL made since an old answer (now deleted) recommended `java.sql.Blob`. Unfortunately once the answer disappears it makes the reference here somewhat anomalous.

Comment: The original post never mentioned SQL! byte[] is fine, until he needs to handle streams. InputStream is the best option, IMO.

Comment: byte[] can be easily wrapped in a ByteArrayInputStream. Store the data, not the stream.

Comment: What implementation of InputStream ? You need to recommend that unless you're talking about interface design

Comment: I don't see any need for a stream here. Derive a stream later if you need it, but it seems completely counter-intuitive for a store of bytes

Comment: Why should I wait half a day for my streaming video to be downloaded into a byte[] for your implementation, when I could be processing it as it comes in?

Comment: That's a requirement that wasn't specified (things that were specified - Excel/ZIP/SOAP)

Comment: So? ZIPs can be big as well. And it says: data agnostic somewhere.

Comment: If in doubt, go for the more flexible option :-). As I said in my first response, byte[] is fine, until his boss asks him to monitor some webcams for movement or something.

Comment: It says data-agnostic "further down the line"

Comment: If in doubt, implement what you have to now, and refactor later as/when you require. Otherwise we'll spend all day debating whether we want to handle latency from our moon probe :-)

Comment: Maybe the transmission object could have both a byte[] for direct data transmission, and an InputStream for deferred/streamed data transmission. What if we need to talk back to the data creator ...

Answer (score 0):

Personally, i would use Spring's [Resource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html) abstraction. This provides a nicer wrapper around the idea of resource that exists somewhere. It provides methods to retrieve an InputStream for when you want to consume the resource.

The easiest implementation for you might be `ByteArrayResource` which encapsulates a byte[]. If that gets too big, then later you can switch to something like a `FileSystemResource`, or a `URLResource`, or one of the various other implementations provided by Spring. But since you always talk to the Resource interface, your client code shouldn't change too much.

Also, since this is just a set of utility classes and interfaces in the Spring API, you can use Resource and its implementations in isolation, without using anything else from Spring.